# Fetching data on second click problem! React js Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I click on the search button the first time API response is "undefined" (based on what console.log says) but the second time it has the response from API.

Why does this happen?

```
xport default function Home() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false);
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    () =>
      shouldFetch
        ? `https://eu-central-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/lottigully-jjrda/service/movies/incoming_webhook/movies?arg=${searchTerm}`
        : null,
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return 'An error has occurred.';

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <div className={style.main_container}>
          <NavBar />
          <Hero />
        </div>
        <div className={style.search_container}>
          <SearchBar
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setShouldFetch(true);
              console.log(searchTerm);
              console.log(data);
            }}
          >
            Search!
          </button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I reckon the data is not set yet when you click the button.

Comment: Can you post the `useSWR` hook code?

Comment: Setting state is an asynchronous operation, `data` won't have updated yet when inside the `onClick` callback. Try moving the `console.log(data);` right before the return statement of your component, you'll see `data` updating correctly then.